# What is the alternative to willRepositionPopoverToRect

Tags: ios, ios9

What is the equivalent, in iOS 9, of `UIPopoverController` behavior `willRepositionPopoverToRect`?

Which class/method should I use to offer similar behavior: something that looks more or less like a bubble on iPad, and that I can position on the screen to give a good contextual reference.